# Lua encryption algorythm

Tags: encryption, lua

So I am working on a encryption algorythm in lua called S22. I have got the encryption part working but the decryption is a lot harder. Any ideas?

My encryption algorythm:

```
function S22Encrypt(MSG, bit)
  local resources = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}
  local finalstring = ""
  local count = 0
  MSG:gsub(".", function(c)
  for i,v in pairs(resources) do
            count = count + 1
             if v == c then
               finalstring = finalstring .. count * bit /69
               count = 0
           end
       end
  end)
  return finalstring
end
```

My attempt at decryption:

```
function S22Decrypt(MSG, bit)
  local resources = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}
    local finalstring = ""
    local count = 0
    MSG:gsub(".", function(c)
    for i,v in pairs(resources) do
          count = count + 1
          if v == c then
            local nmr = count / bit *69
            local count2 = 0
            for a,b in pairs(resources) do
                count2 = count2 + 1
                if count2 == nmr then
                  finalstring = finalstring .. count2 / bit * 69
                end
            end
            count = 0
          end
       end
    end)
    return finalstring
end
```

Comment: What's S22, can you provide a reference to it?

Comment: what's your problem? this is not a debuggin service. you should at least narrow down the problem.

Comment: See also https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Maarten Bodewes, it is my encryption algorithm

Comment: What is your Lua version (5.3+ or old)?

Answer (score 0):

Decrypting is done by trying every possible value of `count` and comparing the corresponding code:

```
function S22Decrypt(MSG, bit)
   local resources = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}
   local finalstring = ""
   local count = 0
   local resource_idx = 0
   while MSG ~= "" do
      count = count + 1
      if count > 1000 then
         return nil, "Can not decrypt"
      end
      resource_idx = resource_idx + 1
      if resource_idx > #resources then
         resource_idx = resource_idx - #resources
         finalstring = finalstring .. " "
      end
      local code = "" .. count * bit /69
      if MSG:sub(1, #code) == code then
         MSG = MSG:sub(#code + 1)
         finalstring = finalstring .. resources[resource_idx]
         count = #resources - resource_idx
         resource_idx = 0
      end
   end
   return finalstring
end
```

Please note that if you are encrypting on one system and decrypting on another then Lua version of encrypting script and Lua version of decrypting script must be either both Lua 5.3+ or both Lua 5.2-
For example, the word "hello" encrypted on Lua 5.1 will not be decryptable on Lua 5.4 (and vice versa) due to integer-to-string differences (`42` vs `42.0`)

Comment: Egor Skriptunoff, thank you but when I run your decrypt code it just freezes my script and refuses to decrypt. I am using lua53, any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: How can I reproduce the problem? What was your MSG and bit (before encrypting)?

Comment: My msg is "Hello World!" and bit is 22

Comment: Works fine for me.  What is the result of encryption on your system?

Comment: My result is: 15.304347826087 15.942028985507 13.710144927536 14.666666666667 17.536231884058 23.594202898551 14.666666666667 11.797101449275 11.159420289855

Comment: I got something working by adding a space before: resources[resource_idx] But it outputs: E L L O   O R L D so not the first letters...

Comment: Why does your result contain space-separated numbers?  The `S22Encrypt` joins them all without spaces in between.